# PHP undefined index using arduino to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arduino-uno

I'm currently reasonably new to both PHP and mySQL and trying to send data to an SQL database using an esp8266 wifi module, but I'm getting the notice

> +IPD,0,348:
> **Notice**:  Undefined index: lic_no in**C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php** onle<2\aphdstt.h/>nln<>< bNie/: dfn nx otoib:xp\dc\s1hr/Etr a uesuy0LSD

But I'm still getting a `null`-value in my SQL database on all columns.

I've tried many of the things suggested on this forum without luck.

My **PHP code**:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'Ecte350';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$lic_no = isset( $_POST['lic_no'] )? $_POST['lic_no']: false;  
$speed = isset( $_POST['speed'] )? $_POST['speed']: false;  
$location = isset( $_POST['location'] )? $_POST['location']: false;  

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = 'INSERT INTO data '.
      '(lic_no, speed, location) '. 'VALUES ("'.$_POST["lic_no"].'", "'.$_POST["speed"].'", "'.$_POST["location"].'" )';

   mysql_select_db('ecte350');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   echo "Entered data successfully\n";

   mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

And this is my **Arduino code**:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>



//////////////////////
// Library Includes //
//////////////////////
// SoftwareSerial is required (even you don't intend on
// using it).
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#include <SparkFunESP8266WiFi.h>



//#define GPSECHO  false

///////////////////
//GPS definitions//
///////////////////

#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>

//SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2); // 
//Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);

//////////////////////////////
// WiFi Network Definitions //
//////////////////////////////
// Replace these two character strings with the name and
// password of your WiFi network.
const char mySSID[] = "amg982";
const char myPSK[] = "ashleigh";

//////////////////////////////
// ESP8266Server definition //
//////////////////////////////
// server object used towards the end of the demo.
// (This is only global because it's called in both setup()
// and loop()).
ESP8266Server server = ESP8266Server(80);

IPAddress comServer (192,168,43,151);
//////////////////
// HTTP Strings //
//////////////////
IPAddress destServer (127,0,0,1);
const String htmlHeader = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                          "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                          "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
                          "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n"
                          "<html>\r\n";

const String httpRequest = "POST /test.php\n"
                           "Host: 192.168.43.151\n"
                           "Connection: close\r\n";

// All functions called from setup() are defined below the
// loop() function. They modularized to make it easier to
// copy/paste into sketches of your own.
void setup() 
{
  // Serial Monitor is used to control the demo and view
  // debug information.

 /////////////
 //GPS SETUP//
 /////////////

  Serial.begin(4800);
 //  GPS.begin(9600);
   // GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCONLY); //recommended  minimum only
   // GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ); //update rate@1HZ
   // GPS.sendCommand(PGCMD_ANTENNA);// anntenna status update



  /*******END******/

  serialTrigger(F("Press any key to begin."));

  // initializeESP8266() verifies communication with the WiFi
  // shield, and sets it up.
  initializeESP8266();

  // connectESP8266() connects to the defined WiFi network.
  connectESP8266();

  // displayConnectInfo prints the Shield's local IP
  // and the network it's connected to.
  displayConnectInfo();

  serialTrigger(F("Press any key to connect client."));
  clientDemo();

  serialTrigger(F("Press any key to test server."));
  serverSetup();
}

void loop() 
{
  serverDemo();
}

void initializeESP8266()
{
  // esp8266.begin() verifies that the ESP8266 is operational
  // and sets it up for the rest of the sketch.
  // It returns either true or false -- indicating whether
  // communication was successul or not.
  // true
  int test = esp8266.begin();
  if (test != true)
  {
    Serial.println(F("Error talking to ESP8266."));
    errorLoop(test);
  }
  Serial.println(F("ESP8266 Shield Present"));
}

void connectESP8266()
{
  // The ESP8266 can be set to one of three modes:
  //  1 - ESP8266_MODE_STA - Station only
  //  2 - ESP8266_MODE_AP - Access point only
  //  3 - ESP8266_MODE_STAAP - Station/AP combo
  // Use esp8266.getMode() to check which mode it's in:
  int retVal = esp8266.getMode();
 // if (retVal != ESP8266_MODE_STA)
 // { // If it's not in station mode.
    // Use esp8266.setMode([mode]) to set it to a specified
    // mode.
    retVal = esp8266.setMode(ESP8266_MODE_STA);
   // if (retVal < 0)
   // {
   //   Serial.println(F("Error setting mode."));
      //errorLoop(retVal);
  //  }
//  }
  Serial.println(F("Mode set to station"));

  // esp8266.status() indicates the ESP8266's WiFi connect
  // status.
  // A return value of 1 indicates the device is already
  // connected. 0 indicates disconnected. (Negative values
  // equate to communication errors.)
  retVal = esp8266.status();
  if (retVal <= 0)
  {
    Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));
    Serial.println(mySSID);
    // esp8266.connect([ssid], [psk]) connects the ESP8266
    // to a network.
    // On success the connect function returns a value >0
    // On fail, the function will either return:
    //  -1: TIMEOUT - The library has a set 30s timeout
    //  -3: FAIL - Couldn't connect to network.
    retVal = esp8266.connect(mySSID, myPSK);
    if (retVal < 0)
    {
      Serial.println(F("Error connecting"));
      errorLoop(retVal);
    }
  }
}

void displayConnectInfo()
{
  char connectedSSID[24];
  memset(connectedSSID, 0, 24);
  // esp8266.getAP() can be used to check which AP the
  // ESP8266 is connected to. It returns an error code.
  // The connected AP is returned by reference as a parameter.
  int retVal = esp8266.getAP(connectedSSID);
  if (retVal > 0)
  {
    Serial.print(F("Connected to: "));
    Serial.println(connectedSSID);
  }

  // esp8266.localIP returns an IPAddress variable with the
  // ESP8266's current local IP address.
  IPAddress myIP = esp8266.localIP();
  Serial.print(F("My IP: ")); Serial.println(myIP);
}

void clientDemo()
{
  // To use the ESP8266 as a TCP client, use the 
  // ESP8266Client class. First, create an object:
  ESP8266Client client;

  // ESP8266Client connect([server], [port]) is used to 
  // connect to a server (const char * or IPAddress) on
  // a specified port.
  // Returns: 1 on success, 2 on already connected,
  // negative on fail (-1=TIMEOUT, -3=FAIL).
  int retVal = client.connect(comServer, 80);
  if (retVal <= 0)
  {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to connect to server."));
    return;
  }

  // print and write can be used to send data to a connected
  // client connection.
  client.print(httpRequest);

  // available() will return the number of characters
  // currently in the receive buffer.
  while (client.available())
    Serial.write(client.read()); // read() gets the FIFO char

  // connected() is a boolean return value - 1 if the 
  // connection is active, 0 if it's closed.
  if (client.connected())
    client.stop(); // stop() closes a TCP connection.
}

void serverSetup()
{
  // begin initializes a ESP8266Server object. It will
  // start a server on the port specified in the object's
  // constructor (in global area)
  server.begin();
  Serial.print(F("Server started!"));
  Serial.println(esp8266.localIP());
  Serial.println();
}

void serverDemo()
{

  float lic_no = 15;
  // available() is an ESP8266Server function which will
  // return an ESP8266Client object for printing and reading.
  // available() has one parameter -- a timeout value. This
  // is the number of milliseconds the function waits,
  // checking for a connection.
  ESP8266Client client = server.available(500);

  if (client) 
  {
    Serial.println(F("Client Connected!"));
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) 
    {
      if (client.available()) 
      {
        char c = client.read();
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) 
        {
         if (client.connect(comServer, 80)==1) {
            client.print("POST /test.php? "); // This
            client.print("&lic_no="); // This
            client.print(lic_no); // And this is what we did in the testing section above. We are making a GET request just like we would from our browser but now with live data from the sensor
            client.println("HTTP/1.1"); // Part of the GET request
            client.println("Host: 192.168.43.151"); // IMPORTANT: If you are using XAMPP you will have to find out the IP address of your computer and put it here (it is explained in previous article). If you have a web page, enter its address (ie.Host: "www.yourwebpage.com")
            client.println("Connection: close\r\n"); // Part of the GET request telling the server that we are over transmitting the message
            client.println(); // Empty line
            client.println(); // Empty line
            client.stop();    // Closing connection to server

          }

        else {
            // If Arduino can't connect to the server (your computer or web page)
              Serial.println("--> connection failed\n");
            }
        }
        if (c == '\n') 
        {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        }
        else if (c != '\r') 
        {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1000);

    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println(F("Client disconnected"));
  }

}

// errorLoop prints an error code, then loops forever.
void errorLoop(int error)
{
  Serial.print(F("Error: ")); Serial.println(error);
  Serial.println(F("Looping forever."));
  for (;;)
    ;
}

// serialTrigger prints a message, then waits for something
// to come in from the serial port.
void serialTrigger(String message)
{
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(message);
  Serial.println();
  while (!Serial.available())
    ;
  while (Serial.available())
    Serial.read();
}
```

Comment: You still use `$_POST` variables instead of the variables you set up. As it stands, even though you check whether the indicies are set, you're still trying to access them even when they're not.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO data '.
      '(lic_no, speed, location) '. 'VALUES ("'.$_POST["lic_no"].'", "'.$_POST["speed"].'", "'.$_POST["location"].'" )';
```

This should be

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO data '.
          '(lic_no, speed, location) '. 'VALUES ("'.$lic_no.'", "'.$speed.'", "'.$location.'" )';
```

Comment: Still missing proper escaping though.

Comment: Where is the actual benefit of using the scalar variables. This improves absolutely nothing